# Mysql. Select line with biggest field, group by other field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple table bc

```
b c
2 5
2 6
```

I'm trying to get line with biggest `c` for each `b`, but I'm getting c=5.
How can I do it in right way?

```
My select:
SET sql_mode = ''; SELECT * FROM `bc`
group by `bc`.b
ORDER BY `bc`.`c` desc
```

Comment: Thank you for showing other question.
I've been searching a lot, and couldn't find it, there were others wrong answers on the same questions, I needed this link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select b, max(c)
from bc
group by b;
```

If you have more columns, you can use a correlated subquery in the `where` clause;

```
select bc.*
from bc
where bc.c = (select max(bc2.c) from bc bc2 where bc2.b = bc.b);
```

Answer (score 0):

use max

```
   select b ,max(c) from table group by b
```

Comment: I need to select LINE with biggest c, not just max c value.
For example, if I'll add new field d, I'll not select line with d from the lime with biggest c, it's not what i need